How to add dynamic members in antmedia Conference
I've used webrtc antmedia conference for create Video conference application and antmedia example provice only 4 members conference so how to add dynamic gridview for members for multiple members.
I want to add multiple members on grid view for conference antmedia rightnow provided sample code is only for 4 members.
My code is this
added 4 SurfaceViewRenderer as static want to add dynamic on that.
 webRTCClient = IWebRTCClient.builder()
                .addRemoteVideoRenderer(player1Renderer, player2Renderer, player3Renderer, player4Renderer)
                .setLocalVideoRenderer(publisherRenderer)
                .setServerUrl(serverUrl)
                .setActivity(this)
                .setDataChannelEnabled(true)
                .setWebRTCListener(defaultConferenceListener)
                .setDataChannelObserver(createDatachannelObserver())
                .build();
webrtc track listener 

 public void onNewVideoTrack(VideoTrack track, String streamId) {
                super.onNewVideoTrack(track, streamId);
                videoTrackStreamIdMap.put(track, streamId);
                Log.d("TAG", "onNewVideoTrack: "+track);
                Log.d("TAG", "onNewVideoTrack sID: "+streamId);
            }

